# Cannot stop and start service when I want

Tags: android, service

That's my MainActivity.
package com.example.simeon.cookingbook.activities;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

import com.example.simeon.cookingbook.R;
import com.example.simeon.cookingbook.services.BackgroundMusic;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent srv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.srv = new Intent(this, BackgroundMusic.class);
        startService(srv);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopService(srv);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopService(srv);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopService(srv);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        startService(srv);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startService(srv);
    }
}
```

That's BackgroundMusic Service.

```
package com.example.simeon.cookingbook.services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

import com.example.simeon.cookingbook.R;

public class BackgroundMusic extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    public MediaPlayer player;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.background);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

I have other activities and I want the music to be heard when my application is opened, but when it goes to background, I don't want music to continue playing. I tried with BaseActivityClass and have read a lot, but still no solution. Please help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you are done using MediaPlayer you need to release it with the [`release()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()) method. I guess the [`onDestroy()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onDestroy()) method of you Service is a good place for that:

```
public class BackgroundMusic extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    public MediaPlayer player;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.background);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public int onDestroy() {
        player.release();
    }


}
```

Comment: But how to do this when my application goes to the background? The service is destroyed only when I stop it directly, but with home button, the music continues.

Comment: @СимеонСимеонов well, activity’s onPause method is called whenever it loses focus. Hence, clicking home button triggers calling onPause in the current activity, so you can invoke stopService there.

Comment: I tried this but the music stops when I go to another activity. So I tried to make base activity which all activities extend, and on it's onPause method I add stopService but then I noticed that on every change of Activity with the Intent, on the base activity the method onPause is activating, so this doesn't work.

Comment: @СимеонСимеонов you are thinking in right direction considering one super class for activities, but in order to stick the service lifecycle to activities it would be better to bind it, instead of starting / stopping via intent. You can check this docs for more information about binding: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html . I can provide more details if you face any difficulties with later today